# Simulate in browser option missing in Visual Studio Community 2017 version 15.7.5

Tags: visual-studio, apache-cordova

I am trying to build apache cordova based cross platform apps on **Visual Studio Community 2017 version 15.7.5** . I am supposed to get "**Simulate in Browser**" where as I only see "**Start**" beside the green button *(see screenshot)*.

Please help!!

[Sceenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJqbq.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Visual Studio has been falling behind with cordova development for years.
Most of us Cordova developers are switching to Visual Studio Code to gain access to the latest features and updates (from Cordova + all Plugins). You will need to get a little more comfortable with the CLI (Command Line Interface) if you wish to be totally up to date.

A quick recommendation to enable you to start teasing your app in the browser.
Install Node.JS (it should already be installed by now), then install the latest Cordova Simulate package from NPM. Use the command line to get into your application directory then run `npm install -g cordova-simulate`  ...then, to test your app in the browser.. you could type **simulate**  ..and your app should now launch in the browser.

Please be sure to read the documentation for the Crodova Browser Simulate package here:https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-simulate